# How to get value of current theme in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

In bokeh you can *set* the theme easily:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
curdoc().theme = "caliber"
```

I am not sure how to simply *get* a string readout of the current theme. I tried `curdoc().theme` and that returned `<bokeh.themes.theme.Theme at 0x21637f022c8>`. Just using printing, `__repr__`, and `__str__` returned similar results. Simply inspecting the output of `dir(curdoc().theme)` didn't reveal any obvious getters I might try (but I'm probably missing something obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Theme` does not contain that information, but you could try:

```py
from bokeh.themes import built_in_themes

theme = curdoc().theme
theme_name = next(k for k, v in built_in_themes.items() if v is theme)
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this: themes are only collections of new default property values (a Theme object). They do not have any intrinsic name at all. There is, externally, a mapping from some standard names to some standard Theme objects for convenience, but *not* the converse (what you are asking for)

Comment: Interesting. Is the default theme one of the named themes (this was actually what I was trying to get)? Basically my question was confused, sort of like asking for the name of a `SimpleNamespace` object, when such objects are just a collection of properties (and if such a collection happens to have a name it is it solely for convenience they aren't really important or essential).